# HTML5 AppCache - Request more space in Firefox

Tags: firefox, offline-caching, html5-appcache

Is it possible to ask a Firefox (version 15) user for more space (> 5MB) for the AppCache?

We're planning to develop a WebApp for a customer with users who are only using Firefox 15 (or IE8) and the whole product database (800 products with some attributes and images) and a order list generator should be able to work offline.

Any help or other solutions based on Firefox 15 or IE8 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`browser.cache.offline.capacity` seems to be the pref you want.  By default it's 500M, which really ought to be plenty!

Go to `about:config` and type 'offline' in the search box to get to the pref.

http://www.tweakguides.com/Firefox_10.html

Lots more information in mozillazine, but it's down at the moment; use google's cache:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Y607-mxIMCEJ:kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.offline.capacity+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-beta

Comment: I think the appcache would be stored in the DOM storage, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage - dom.storage.default_quota (by default 5120 KB)